# Is it ok if I start an opinion composition with the word 'Indeed'?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, writing-style, sentence-starts

I was just wondering, is it's OK to begin an opinion composition with the word 'Indeed' in the first sentence? For example:

> Indeed I believe people's consumerism is one of the main causes for our planet's demise.

(In case the opinion composition is about whether or not consumerism is a big problem.)

Comment: In your example, the word "indeed" emphasises the truth (by implication, possibly against expectations) of *the fact that you believe something*. It's got no particular implications for the truth or falsity of whatever you happen to believe. For example - *"Everyone knows he's barking mad. Indeed, he genuinely believes the moon is made of green cheese"*.

Comment: But the point is well made that *Indeed* has to follow something. You can't simply launch out with *indeed*.

Comment: Indeed you can't. Andrew.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for proving my point. Your comment wouldn't work if it didn't follow mine.

Comment: The clue was in the _Andrew_.

Answer (score 1):

[*Indeed*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indeed) emphasizes the truth of a claim already made.

This is most obvious for the word used as an interjection:

> “I'm a great runner.”
>
> “Indeed!”

As a sentence adverb, it's usually used to elaborate on the truth of a claim just made:

> Consumerism is a major problem for the world today. Indeed, I believe people's consumerism is one of the main causes for our planet's demise.

[The entry at Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/indeed) expresses this well:

> When you use the word indeed, you are underscoring that something is true. The word is also used when you want to introduce a point that's even truer than the last one you made. “Yes, I passed the test, and indeed, got the highest score in the class.” In other words, it's a polite way to say: “Take that!”